# Ubuntu freezes constantly, any way to fix?

Tags: 18.04, freeze, crash

My PC is constantly freezing multiple times every 10-20 minutes and the only way to continue using it is to reboot the PC, but only to have it freeze again a a few minutes.

Strangely I can still hear sound coming from the PC. When I open the logs, I always get the messages,

> AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.

and

> ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [_SB.SMIB],
>   AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180531/dsfield-594)

or something similar to the last one.
Any help is appreciated, I am new to Linux and am trying to resolve this frustrating issue

My system configuration is:

```
CPU: Ryzen 2200G
GPU: Integrated Vega 8 GPU
OS:  Ubuntu 18.04.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably more of a hardware problem than a problem with Ubuntu. First thing to check is if your motherboard BIOS is up to date for the Ryzen 2200g.